# MS Access sql - multiple joins with AND gives Cartesian product?

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, cartesian-product

```
-- MS ACCESS sql to present row based data as column based
-- Gives too many rows probably Cartesian product. If I have 5 toys with one color and one weight each I expect 5 rows, but get more
SELECT
t.ToyId 
,t.ToyName
,p1.TextValue as 'Color'
,p2.FloatValue as 'Weight'
FROM (my_toys t
LEFT OUTER JOIN properties p1 ON (t.ToyId = p1.ToyId)  AND (p1.propertyId='Color'))) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN properties p2 ON (t.ToyId = p2.ToyId)  AND (p2.propertyId='Weight'))
```

I am making a demo of a future MySQL database in MS Access SQL. I have a table of Toys, and I have ONE table of propeties like Color, Weight, Length etc. Each row in the properties table represent one property for one toy, so it is a row based storage. Examples of rows in the properties table could be:

- Toy=1; ProperyType='Color'; TextValue='Blue'; FloatValue=null;
- Toy=1; ProperyType='Weight' TextValue=null; FloatValue=42;
- Toy=1;ProperyType='Length' TextValue=null; FloatValue=123;
- Toy=2;ProperyType='Color'; TextValue='Red'; FloatValue=null;

When I manage to get the syntax right the above SQL gives not one row per Toy with columns for Color and Weight, but instead the Cartesian product, at least too many rows. The aim of this sql-question is to get transform a row-based data model to a column-based for better human readability.

I have made similar constructs for views in MySQL that works, but I cannot understand what I make wrong in the MS Access SQL code. Can anyone help me out?

(Please note my actual project is not for Toys so the code may contain some typing errors)

Comment: I'm not accustomed to EAV structures, but if you want the output to show only one row per toy I think you need a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Parenthesis looks incorrect.
I count 5 ( and 7 )

Comment: I know access loves adding )'s it may be an order of operation issue.  Can you remove them or use subselects instead?

Comment: It's hard to help you if you yourself acknowledge that the query you typed is not accurate (quote: *may contain some typing errors*). The problem could very well be in some detail you haven't transcribed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The compound condition on the left joins may be causing problems with the order of operation on the ()'s access adds...

```
SELECT
t.ToyId 
,t.ToyName
,p1.TextValue as 'Color'
,p2.FloatValue as 'Weight'
FROM my_toys t
LEFT OUTER JOIN (Select * from properties where  p1.propertyId='Color') p1 
   ON t.ToyId = p1.ToyId
LEFT OUTER JOIN (Select * from properties where p2.propertyId='Weight') p2 
   ON t.ToyId = p2.ToyId
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks xQbert, I tried your solution. When I still got too many rows I really looked at my data tables again, and it turned out I had another identifier to the "Toy", lets call it Owner. So there were actually more than one Toy with each ToyId, so it way my mistake all the way. But if I had not got your solution I would have trashed Access as beeing unusable!

Thanks also to all comments, from this issue I learnt a few things.

1. I can now make joins and joins on subquerys in MS Access SQL!
2. Before sending questions to you guys, I shall always make a simple, barebone example. I can then find my own stupid mistakes, and you have working code and a example database to test on.
3. I should not mistrust MS Access SQL so much! In this example my first thought was that multiple joins with AND is not possible due to limitations in the language.